# Set default header for every fetch() request

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, authorization, fetch-api

Is it possible, using the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), to set default headers for every single request?
What I want to do is set an `Authorization` header whenever there is a json web token in the `localStorage`. My current solution is to set the headers with this function:

```
export default function setHeaders(headers) {
    if(localStorage.jwt) {
        return {
            ...headers,
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.jwt}`
        }
    } else {
        return headers;
    }
}
```

Setting the headers in a fetch request would then look like this:

```
return fetch('/someurl', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: setHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
    })
```

But there has to be a better way to do this. I'm currently developing a React/Redux/Express app if that is of any help.

Comment: If for some reason you do not want to use existing wrappers around fetch, writing one to add authorization header should be straight forward.

Answer (score 39):

Creating a `fetch` wrapper could solve your problem:

```
function updateOptions(options) {
  const update = { ...options };
  if (localStorage.jwt) {
    update.headers = {
      ...update.headers,
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.jwt}`,
    };
  }
  return update;
}

export default function fetcher(url, options) {
  return fetch(url, updateOptions(options));
}
```

You also get the added benefit of being able to switch your request client easily for all the calls in your application if you decide you like Axios or other package better. And you can do other things like check if `options.body` is an object and add the `'Content-Type: application/json` header.

Answer (score 10):

Andri Möll created a [FetchDefaults.js](https://github.com/moll/js-fetch-defaults) mixin for `fetch` that sets fetch defaults:

```js
var Url = require("url")
var assign = require("oolong").assign
var merge = require("oolong").merge
var PARSE_QUERY = false
var PROTOCOL_RELATIVE = true // Enable //example.com/models to mimic browsers.

exports = module.exports = function(fetch, rootUrl, defaults) {
  if (typeof rootUrl === "string") rootUrl = parseUrl(rootUrl)
  else defaults = rootUrl, rootUrl = null
  return assign(exports.fetch.bind(null, fetch, rootUrl, defaults), fetch)
}

exports.fetch = function(fetch, rootUrl, defaults, url, opts) {
  if (rootUrl != null) url = rootUrl.resolve(url)
  if (typeof defaults === "function") defaults = defaults(url, opts)
  return fetch(url, opts == null ? defaults : merge({}, defaults, opts))
}

function parseUrl(url) {
  return Url.parse(url, PARSE_QUERY, PROTOCOL_RELATIVE)
}
```

Distributed under [AGPL-3.0-only](https://spdx.org/licenses/AGPL-3.0-only.html) license

Answer (score 9):

You could use [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) instead of fetch, with Interceptors

```
const setAuthorization = (token) => {

  api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
    return config;
  });

}
```

Where Api is an axios Object with a base URL

```
const api= axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://exemple.com'
});
```

And when you get your token, u just have to call the function setAuthorization.

*Source: [Axios README.md](https://github.com/axios/axios#custom-instance-defaults)*

Comment: You can use axios to set your authorization headers and then use normal fetch request and the headers will be set for the fetch request as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can override default fetch api:

```
var originalFetch = window.fetch;
window.fetch = function (input, init) {
    if (!init) {
        init = {};
    }
    if (!init.headers) {
        init.headers = new Headers();
    }

    // init.headers could be: 
    //   `A Headers object, an object literal, 
    //    or an array of two-item arrays to set request’s headers.`
    if (init.headers instanceof Headers) {
        init.headers.append('MyHeader', 'Value');
    } else if (init.headers instanceof Array) {
        init.headers.push(['MyHeader', 'Value']);
    } else {
        // object ?
        init.headers['MyHeader'] = 'Value';
    }
    return originalFetch(input, init);
};
```

References:

- https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-method
- https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#requestinit

Answer (score 2):

A quick and unrecommended hack is to redefine the default `.fetch()` function:

```
const oldFetch = window.fetch;
window.fetch = function() {
    arguments[1].headers = { 'blahblah' : 'blabla' };
    return oldFetch.apply(window, arguments);
}
```

Code is untested and unfinished. If you decide to use this answer, check `arguments.length`, add code to preserve existing headers, etc. etc. I'm just providing the direction for further exploration.